# Propagate container query to childrens child

Tags: javascript, css, sass, responsive, container-queries

I'm currently testing out some stuff with [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries). It feels great so far, except one issue.
I have a header with 100% width, with 2 slots(shadowRoot), `left & right`. Inside of the right area I have 2 buttons that should become icon buttons when the header is below a certain width(See attached image). I would like to only have some global breakpoints and not do specific widths for each div, so the container should be the entire header. Though, since it's the buttons that should change appearance when the container changes, I would like to propagate the container "trigger" down to the slot `right`. My question is, is this possible at the moment?

So, `Header` is my container, and I want to propagate this down to the 2 `Button` for them to change into icons. It's unfortunately not possible in this specific case to just remove the `right` div and have the buttons as direct children to `Header`.
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think we can probably guess your HTML structure but please include it preferably as part of a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example